apache-spark-sql: convert given string into Date YYYY-MM-DD format
Given String can be in format of any of the below :

'5/8/2021 12:00:00 AM' or
'05/8/2021 12:00:00 AM' or
'5/08/2021 12:00:00 AM' or
'05/08/2021 12:00:00 AM'

Needed output = '2021-05-08' in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format of Spark SQL. Any advise is appreciated. Tried like below:
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX('5/8/2021 12:00:00 AM', '/', -1),
    '-',
    LPAD(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('5/8/2021 12:00:00 AM', '/', 1), '/', -1), 2, '0'),
    '-',
    LPAD(REGEXP_REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('5/8/2021 12:00:00 AM', '/', 1), ' ', -1), '.* ', ''), 2, '0')
  ) AS converted_date;


Assuming you have a column timestamp_column in the table some_table, you can use unix_timestamp and coalesce to parse the dates, provided that the date is in one of the specified formats.
select coalesce(to_date(to_timestamp(unix_timestamp(timestamp_column, 'M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss a')), 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
                to_date(to_timestamp(unix_timestamp(timestamp_column, 'MM/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss a')), 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
                to_date(to_timestamp(unix_timestamp(timestamp_column, 'M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a')), 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
                to_date(to_timestamp(unix_timestamp(timestamp_column, 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a')), 'yyyy-MM-dd')) AS timestamp_column
from some_table


Try if this works

SELECT
to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('5/8/2021 12:00:00 AM', 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a')), 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS converted_date


getting error as Caused by: org.apache.org.spark.SparkUpgradeException: [INCOSISTENT_BEHAVIOR_CROSS_VERSION.PARSET_DATETIME_BY_NEW_PARSER] Caused by  java.time.format.DatTimeParseException: Text '5/8/2021 12:00:00 AM' could not be parsed at index 0
